# Is there a way to view two blocks of code from the same file simultaneously in Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublimetext2

Is there a way to view two blocks of code from the same file simultaneously in Sublime Text? I can't find anything in the view options.

Comment: You can have the same file open in a separate tab/column.  They will both be edited at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

In the nav go `View => Layout => Columns:2` (`alt+shift+2`) and open your file again in the other pane (i.e. click the other pane and use `ctrl+p filename.py`)

It appears you can also reopen the file using the command `File -> New View into File` which will open the current file in a new tab

Comment: I used command+p filename.py and the file didn't open. (I'm on a mac)

Comment: It would be `⌘ + P` in mac